# Adding ProgressDialog as Async Task is slowing down the performance

Tags: android, progressdialog

This is my code for Login.

```
public void Login_Click(View view) {
HashMap<String, String> op_Config = XMLParser
        .parse(LoginActivity.this);
}
```

It takes around 4 Sec to finish executing. So I added progress dialog like this.

```
public void Login_Click(View view) {
 new IsLogedIn().execute();
}

class IsLogedIn extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
{   
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    showDialog(progress_bar_type);
}   
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... value) {
    try
    {   
        HashMap<String,String> op_Config = XMLParser.parse(LoginActivity.this);
        finish();
        Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainMenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);  
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }               
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);       
}
}
```

But now it is taking more than 1 min to finish.

Comment: You should move the code from `finish()` to `startActivity` into the `onPostExecute` method since these should happen from the UI thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try doing like this

```
  class IsLogedIn extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
    {   
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }   
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... value) {
        try
        {   
            HashMap<String,String> op_Config = XMLParser.parse(LoginActivity.this);      
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }               
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

    if(dilog.isShowing()){
      dismissDialog(progress_bar_type); 
      }

     finish();
     startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainMenuActivity.class));    

    }
    }
```

Comment: When you do it in background it takes time to finish and start new activity...because UIprocess is so hard to happen in background so try max to do it in pre or post execute..Unavoidable cases only you shud update UI from background...That must be the reason your process was lagging...

Comment: Ok. So UIProcess will take much time, When we are doing it in background..Thanks.